# RxJava / Retrofit Call for every item in a reponse

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I call my API with retrofit/rxJava and I get an **Observable** response like a **Single List** of **BreedDog**

. You can see my code :

```
compositeDisposable.add(breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getBreedDogs(name)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<BreedDog>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<BreedDog> breedDogList) {
                    Log.e("test", "okPresenter");
                    view.displayBreedDogs(breedDogToViewModelMapper.map(breedDogList));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("test", "errorPresenter : " + e.toString());
                    // handle the error case
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }));
```

This works but now, for every items of this list I need to call my API to get an URL image and update my list..
But I don't know how... I tried change my Single response in Observable and used operator like flatMap or flatMapIterate.. etc But all time I got errors with the Object.. like no instance...etc

This is an example :

```
breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getBreedDogs(name)
            .flatMapIterable(breedDogs -> breedDogs)
            .map( item ->   breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getImageBreedDog(item.getId())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<BreedImageResponse>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<BreedImageResponse> breedImageResponses) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e("test", "errorPresenter : " + e.toString());
                            // handle the error case
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                        }
                    })));
```

Do I use the good way ? Or need to change something ?

Answer (score 0):

Without the signature of the repository it's hard to say exactly what's wrong, but you do mention that `getBreedDogs` returns a `Single<List<BreedDogs>>`. If this is the case, `Single` doesn't have a `flatMapIterable` as far as I know, but it has [`flattenAsObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) which can be used to do what you want I think.

It will map the list inside the single and emit its items as observables. This means you can no longer use `map` and have to switch to `flatMap`:

```
.flattenAsObservable(breedDogs -> breedDogs) 
.flatMapSingle(item -> breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getImageBreedDog(item.getId()))
```

*`flatMapSingle` is used because we're flat mapping `Singles` in this case*

Another thing I noticed is that your "subscription part" is inside the `map` and you want this out of it. so ideally you'd move outside like:

```
.flattenAsObservable(breedDogs -> breedDogs) 
.flatMapSingle(item -> breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getImageBreedDog(item.getId()))
.subscribeWith(/*...*/);
```

The schedulers is up to you. If you want your images to be downloaded in parallel I'd recommend to keep them inside the `flatMapSingle`.

Last thing, it seems that you want to receive a `List<BreedImageResponse>`, so I'd use `toList()`. Putting everything together:

```
breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getBreedDogs(name)
  .flattenAsObservable(breedDogs -> breedDogs) 
  .flatMapSingle(item ->
    breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.getImageBreedDog(item.getId())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  )
  .toList()
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<BreedImageResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<BreedImageResponse> breedImageResponses) { 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I found a solution wich looks like your answer. I put my code below

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to solve the problem :

```
public Single<List<BreedDogWithImage>> searchDogs(String name) {
    return getBreedDogs(name)
            .flatMapIterable(breedDogs -> breedDogs)
            .flatMap(breedDog -> getImageBreedDogs(breedDog.getId())
                    .flatMapIterable(breedDogWithImages -> breedDogWithImages))
            .toList();
}
```

And so I can call it like this :

```
public void searchBreedDogs(String name) {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    compositeDisposable.add(breedDogsDisplayDataRepository.searchDogs(name)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<BreedDogWithImage>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<BreedDogWithImage> breedDogWithImages) {
                    Log.e("test", "okCall" + breedDogWithImages);
                    view.displayBreedDogs(breedDogToViewModelMapper.map(breedDogWithImages));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("test", "error ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
}
```